# kubernetes pod failing due to permission denied

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I'm trying to install MariaDB using helm on K8s cluster. I was able to install successfully using below helm command.

Before I installed I created a PV using below manifest file.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: nfs-pv
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 20Gi
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Recycle
  storageClassName: nfs-pc
  mountOptions:
    - hard
    - nfsvers=4.1
  nfs:
    path: /nfs/data
    server: 192.168.56.1
```

`kubectl apply -f pv.yml`

`helm install my-mariadb bitnami/mariadb -n my-mariadb`

Everything else looks good except pod is not coming up healthy because volume permissions.

```
kubectl -n my-mariadb logs pods/my-mariadb-0 
mariadb 13:58:45.97 INFO  ==> 
mariadb 13:58:45.98 INFO  ==> Welcome to the Bitnami mariadb container
mariadb 13:58:45.98 INFO  ==> Subscribe to project updates by watching https://github.com/bitnami/containers
mariadb 13:58:45.98 INFO  ==> Submit issues and feature requests at https://github.com/bitnami/containers/issues
mariadb 13:58:45.98 INFO  ==> 
mariadb 13:58:45.99 INFO  ==> ** Starting MariaDB setup **
mariadb 13:58:46.00 INFO  ==> Validating settings in MYSQL_*/MARIADB_* env vars
mariadb 13:58:46.02 INFO  ==> Initializing mariadb database
mkdir: cannot create directory '/bitnami/mariadb/data': Permission denied
```

What values I need to change to fix this permission issue.
I've seen some other posts where folks asking create an init container and add templates and I do not want to go with that path.
and also I do not want want to run container as root.

Any suggestions ?

I've also tried to set volume permissions with helm install command -
Now this init container failing to change the permission.

`helm install my-mariadb bitnami/mariadb --set volumePermissions.enabled=true -n my-mariadb`

```
kubectl get pods -n my-mariadb 
NAME           READY   STATUS                  RESTARTS        AGE
my-mariadb-0   0/1     Init:CrashLoopBackOff   7 (2m54s ago)   14m



kubectl logs my-mariadb-0 -c volume-permissions --namespace my-mariadb
chown: changing ownership of '/bitnami/mariadb': Operation not permitted
```